# Nested For loop multidimensional array search

Tags: c#

Got a silly question im struggling with.

Im trying to step through a C# Multidimensional array using nested for loops, but i cant get the result i want and im thinking its just a stupid problem with my code.

```
string search = txtString.Text;

        int iLoop;
        int jloop;
        int iResult = -1;

        for (iLoop = 0; iLoop < sounds.GetLength(0) ; iLoop++)
        {
            for (jloop = 0; jloop < sounds.GetLength(1) ; jloop++)
            {

                string result;
                result = sounds[iLoop,jloop];

                if (result == search)
                {
                    iResult = iloop;
                }
            }
        }

            if (iResult == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Result not found");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Result found at position " + iResult);                    
            }            
    }
```

It searches the array, and returns a positive result if the answer is found, but the result position is always "Result found at position 1".

What have i done wrong?

Comment: Maybe because the result is always in the first row?

Comment: How is `sounds` declared and what is assigned to it?

Comment: btw, in your code notion of `position` corresponds to number of `row` but not pair `row,column`. Was that made intentional?

Comment: @aleksey.berezan Second row actually, since 0 = first row?

Comment: @RBarryYoung, I have a habbit calling 0-th position as `zeroth` and 1-th one as `first`. But let it be 1st = second row, for convenience :)

Comment: @NXSmiggy, try to declare `int jResult = -1;` variable and save it along with the `iResult` like `if (result == search){iResult = iloop;jResult=jloop;}` and show print it. Maybe it'll give some hint.

Comment: For one thing, your outer loop variable is `iLoop`, but you're setting `iResult = iloop;` Is there an `iloop` defined somewhere we don't see? Or is this just a typo in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing only one dimension (`iResult`). It can always be 1, but second dimension (`jresult`) can vary.

And just reminder for future projects in different languages. Try no to use `if (result == search)` for strings. Use `Equal` or `Compare methods`.

Comment: In C#, `==` is perfectly fine for primitives and strings.

Comment: Yes, in C#... but if he switch eg to Java or another language, it can create a lot of troubles for beginner. Better is use same notation in all languages and you can be sure, you have it OK :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two indices to look up: jloop  and iLoop , probably you will get various jloop values in the 2D array

Answer (score 0):

Also check the name on the parameter you use, sometimes you call it `iLoop`, others `iloop`.
Be consistent! :)

I guess the answer is always in row 1, you just pring the `i` value, print also the `j` value `jLoop`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that this code snippet will continue searching even after it has found a match.  So in fact what you are finding is the *last* position of the matched text.

As an aside, perhaps instead of reporting only the matching `iLoop`, you could report both the matching `iLoop` and `jLoop`.  Or, you can report a single index as `iLoop * sounds.GetLength(0) + jLoop`